# What are good docking frameworks for Java/Swing?

Tags: java, swing, frameworks, docking

I'm looking for a good lightweight Java docking framework.

I know that Netbeans and Eclipse can be used as RCP, but I'm looking for something a little bit more lightweight.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Swing / AWT frameworks:

- [Raven Docking](http://raven.java.net/ravenDocking/download.html) Apache 2; 0.2 MB
- [MyDoggy](http://mydoggy.sourceforge.net/) LGPL; only JARs: 0.7 MB; Dec 2010
- [VLDocking](http://code.google.com/archive/p/vldocking/) LGPL; 0.4 MB
- [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/index.html) CDDL/GPL; 4.6 MB (platform.zip)
- Eclipse CPL or EPL ? only swt (?)
- [InfoNode](http://sourceforge.net/projects/infonode/) GPL or Commercial
- [Sanaware](http://www.javadocking.com/) GPL or Commercial full zip 0.3MB
- [Docking Frames](http://dock.javaforge.com/) LGPL; 3 MB
- [Jide](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/dock.htm) commercial; <3MB
- [FlexDock](http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/flexdock/) MIT; 0.4 MB; Nov 2011

JavaFX frameworks:

- [TiwulFX-Dock](https://github.com/panemu/tiwulfx-dock) MIT; 22 KB
- [DockFX](https://github.com/RobertBColton/DockFX) MPL-2.0; 44 KB

Inactive projects

- [SwingDocking](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swingdocking/) seems to me fully functional and fast; Apache license 2; Oct 2007
- [XUI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xui/) will be further developed here?; MPL; 1.6 MB (XUI-jdk15.zip); Feb 2008
- JDocking CDDL; 1.3 MB (v0.8.zip) the docking part of netbeans
- [JRichClient](http://code.google.com/p/jrichclient/) GPL; derivation of flexdock; Nov 2007

Answer (score 12):

I once evaluated several docking frameworks (including the already mentioned [flexdock](https://flexdock.dev.java.net/) and [mydoggy](http://mydoggy.sourceforge.net/) and [jdocking](https://jdocking.dev.java.net/).

Finaly I came to [Docking Frames](http://dock.javaforge.com/index.html), which I can really recommend. It is easy to use but still feature rich + good documentation and quick support from developer via forum.

Comment: The link is utterly dead. Is this the same framework? http://docking-frames.org

Answer (score 4):

I have successfully used **FlexDock** in the past but it seems not well supported and it is quite hard to start with (this is a quite complex framework for docking). FlexDock is open source.

Besides, more recently, I have enjoyed using **MyDoggy** which is well supported and quite easy to use (very well documented with enough examples and tutorials). Its main drawback (for me) is the difficulty to adapt its look when using 3rd-party LAFs (like Substance for instance). But in general I really like it. If I remember correctly, it is quite a lightweight library. I would recommend it for any use (it is open source and free to use) for its good API.

Answer (score 3):

See the [infonode docking windows](http://www.infonode.net/index.html?idw).

They have a gpl version and a commercial version, but the licenses are not that expensive. Robust and good looking if you select the right skin (we use the ShapedGradientDockingTheme which looks a little like eclipse).

Comment: Not expensive? A commercial Infonode docking license costs $6000!

Comment: $6000 is for a site license, single user is $300.

Answer (score 3):

We use VLDocking from vlsolutions (http://vldocking.com) quite successfully in 3 of our products. They have some open-source license compatible with GPL.

Answer (score 3):

JIDE has quite a few components including a docking framework.  The core of JIDE is open source but they also have several commercial libraries.  The docking framework is commercial.

http://www.jidesoft.com/products/component.htm

Answer (score 3):

I've just released another docking framework.  It's really lightweight and available under the Apache 2.0 license.

Raven Docking:

http://raven.java.net/ravenDocking/index.html