# First database desktop application

Tags: java, database, swing, jframe, desktop-application

I am quite novice to Java (re-learning) and I am trying to make a database desktop application. The system will be used for a recording the incoming and outgoing of goods for a wholesaler.

I had done similar kind of application (Student Management System) before as my college project (2 yrs before) without adequate knowledge of OOP.

1. first I had a `JFrame` for log in, and when logged, the login frame would close showing the other frame.
2. A frame would act as control panel (similar to dashboard) for navigating.
3. The other frame would be provide a specific interface and will close on going back showing the control frame and hiding the closed panel.
4. `Abstract table model` class was used for fetching the query and `JTable` or some table was used for displaying the result.
5. To sum up, I simply had lots of frames that would hide and show, and **Display** table

To be honest, I , at that time, knew nothing more than what was in the book which i didn't bother to scrutinize every line of code, and still haven't seen such an application.

My Question is, how should be a the cascade of JFrames be, everything is managed within a single frame?  Also I would be grateful on suggestion of **framework** (for such kind of application) and any sample project (if any).

Comment: and why not go web ? ... there is good and easy framework like 'Play'  ... just saying'

Comment: @AloisCochard I don't know in which direction i am going.

Comment: honestly for me deskop java application have no future, web development is not that hard. Take a look at this: http://www.playframework.org/ and make your own opinion :)

Comment: @AliosCochard sure i will look at it, but currently i have to do this (client is always right), I am doing php right now, and i have interest in java too, sure i will have a look at it. Just wanted to know if I should do same for my client what i've done for college

Comment: @expermientX ho yeah, client is always right - I know that too ;) good luck !

Comment: Maybe use a DockingFramework: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304874/what-are-good-docking-frameworks-for-java-swing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ..how should be a the cascade of JFrames be, everything is managed within a single frame?

There are a number of options:

- Remove the old components and add new
  ones.  Not highly recommended.  Error
  prone and usually unnecessary.
- Use JInternalFrames in a JDesktopPane for multiple views of the same types of data.
- Swap one set of components for another using CardLayout.
- Put each set of components into a JTabbedPane.
- If there are always logically a fixed number of objects (e.g. product tree, product description, stock levels by store table), you might put them in different areas of a BorderLayout, or toss in a JSplitPane to allow resizing of space between GUI elements.

See the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) lesson of the Java Tutorial for ideas & examples.

Comment: Also consider using [Java Web Start](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136112.html) for deployment.

Comment: @trashgod Great idea.  But I prefer linking to http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info to describe JWS.  SO's info tag on JWS includes **all** the best links I could find on the topic. ;)

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for this comprehensive resource.