# A layout implementation such as Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, swing, layout, swt, awt

I have been working on a project model and pretty much completed it. Now I must implement the view of the project. I like eclipse view layout very much and tried to implement like this but I couln't. And then download source code of eclipse but couldn't find my specific code snippet in all of the source code. I mean I want to take basic layout implementation like eclipse Coolbar,ctabfolder and events. any suggections ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like the Eclipse look and feel and the components used, you should have a look into the technologies used with Eclipse:

- [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) is the GUI toolkit. It differs from Swing in that it uses the native widgets, if possible. This makes an application using it behave more like a native application than Swing does, which has its own set of components. You will find the raw components that you mention here.
- [JFace](http://wiki.eclipse.org/The_Official_Eclipse_FAQs#JFace) is an application framework based on SWT. It provides higher level conceptual components.
- [Eclipse RCP](http://www.eclipse.org/home/categories/rcp.php) is a platform for building application. It takes away some common tasks of application building but, of course, you need to learn the concepts first.

Swing has similar components, but does not use the native widgets. It draws them itself. In my opinion Swing is easier to learn and to use but the results of SWT are often nicer - you can often "feel" that a Swing application behaves not completely right. It is better if Swing applications do not try to mimic the native look and feel to avoid the [uncanny valley](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncanny_Valley) effect. So expect your resulting application to look and feel different.

There are more documentation and third-party libraries available for Swing, for example the very nice [Netbeans RCP](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/) that let's you easily build applications.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a docking framework. What the best framework is is open for debate.
You might have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304874/what-are-good-docking-frameworks-for-java-swing) for a list of popular frameworks