# What is docking framework and when to use it?

Tags: java, swing, docking

I do not really understand the concept of docking the Swing frame. I would like to know how should I imagine the process of docking the frame and why one should use it, in which situation. Isnt just simple Swing JFrame enough? hanks for your input.

Comment: Most modern browsers use a type docking framework, allowing to open multiple pages in a single window, but to also allowing you to "undock" any of the tabs into its own window

Answer (score 3):

A docking framework lets you organize kinds of "subwindows" inside another window (think of InternalFrames but more flexible).
Your GUI is very flexible and the end user can reorganize it.

Eclipse, Netbeans and others IDE contains dockable windows.

You can find some docking frameworks listed here : [What are good docking frameworks for Java/Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304874/what-are-good-docking-frameworks-for-java-swing)